# How is de Rham cohomology useful?

Tags: smooth-manifolds, de-rham-cohomology

I'm learning about smooth manifolds from the last part of ***Introduction to Manifolds***.  Despite the fact I read this part few times I feel like I can't master it because I need to understand how it is useful.

Can you give me a couple of examples explaining how de Rahm cohomology is useful? I understand the given definition, and how the computation is made easier by using the Mayer Vietoris sequence, but I really struggle to find the following:

1. Why is the de Rham cohomology useful? If we wouldn't be using it what sorts of problem would be hard? (Some people say they're useful to solve equations, but how? the few examples I've seen are quite obscure to me.)
2. Maybe a set of 5 examples with computation included that might actually be useful to understand how they're actually computed. You can even give me a web page or a *Youtube* video (the latter would be better) with few exercises.

Comment: One partial answer: as in other "geometries" (algebraic geometry, for instance), and as for most (co)homology theories, the main advantage is that cohomology groups are linear invariants of a manifold: they are vector spaces (or abelian groups), hence they are often relatively easy to manipulate and compare (think of exact sequences and so on), and with them you can gain useful information on your manifold, which is in principle much more complicated to work with. For instance, you can tell that two manifolds are not isomorphic just because they don't have isomorphic cohomology groups.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The one-sentence explanation is that cohomology on a space $X$ answers the question of when you can promote local solutions of a problem to global solutions; that is, if you can solve a problem on each element of a cover of $X$, can you patch those individual solutions together to get a global solution?

For de Rham cohomology, the first question is one of closed versus exact differential forms. Given a closed form $\omega$ on a smooth and (let's say) compact manifold $X$, is there another form $\eta$ with $d\eta = \omega$? The answer is easy on a star-shaped patch of $X$: just integrate. (I'm glossing over reduced versus unreduced cohomology, so you have to be more careful with the dimension of $\omega$ to get a definitive answer here.) With a bit more work, the same answer holds for a coordinate patch diffeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^n$. That means we know the answer locally on $X$, but it's not clear how to proceed to a global answer. The classical example is $\mathbb{R}^2\setminus{0}$, where the form
\begin{align*}
d\theta = \frac{- y\, dx + x\, dy}{x^2 + y^2}
\end{align*}
is closed but not exact by Stokes' theorem, since its integral over a loop around $0$ doesn't vanish. That last part is a hint that topology is involved, since we can look at $\int_{\gamma} d\theta$ as a function of $\gamma$ and consider how it varies under smooth homotopy.

Still, the idea of closed versus exact differential forms may seem a bit arbitrary. One way of resolving it is to note that de Rham cohomology group $H^0(X)$ is the space of functions that are locally constant (as there are no (nonzero, I guess) forms of negative degree). Under some reasonable assumptions on $X$, that means that $H^0(X)$ is just the $\mathbb{R}$-space of connected components of $X$. The higher groups have similar topological ramifications that would take a bit too long to describe, but the point is that despite the de Rham cohomology defined in terms of a certain set of differential equations, they're fundamentally topological objects.

To that end, the answer to the question of what the de Rham cohomology groups are good for might be that they're a particularly useful and concrete way of defining and  computing the cohomology of a space. There are multiple cohomology theories (not all of which are well-defined for all spaces): singular cohomology, cellular cohomology, etc. Because of abstract nonsense, these construction generally coincide under reasonable conditions on $X$. The short explanation is that all of these start with the same $H^0$ and satisfy certain axioms that force the higher $H^*$ to agree.

Quicker and simpler explanations for the specific questions you asked:

1) Some assorted applications:

- De Rham cohomology is invariant under homotopy equivalence (in the smooth category), which allows us to easily prove that two manifolds are not homeomorphic or homotopy equivalent. Furthermore, cohomology comes with a ring structure that gives an extra condition to require for equivalence.
- Homotopy groups are hard to compute; cohomology groups are generally much easiser. The Hurewicz theorem states that the lowest homotopy and homology group of a reasonable space coincide if they're in dimension $\geq 2$; in dimension $1$, you have to abelianize $\pi_1$ first. (Homology groups can generally be obtained from cohomology via, say, Poincare duality.)
- Rational homology groups (i.e., $\pi_* \otimes \mathbb{Q})$ can be obtained from $H_*(X) \otimes \mathbb{Q}$ via minimal models, under some mild restrictions on the underlying space.
- Closed, simply-connected $4$-manifolds are determined by their intersection forms, which in the smooth case is similar to the the map $H^2(X) \otimes H^2(X) \to \mathbb{R}$ defined by $(\alpha, \beta) \to \int_X \alpha \wedge \beta$. (It's only "similar to" in part because de Rham cohomology is naturally defined over $\mathbb{R}$, while we need to work over $\mathbb{Z}$ here.) With a lot of work, this leads to proving that there exist closed, simply-connected manifolds that have no smooth structure.
- For an Eilenberg-MacLane space $K(G, A)$ with $A$ abelian, the map $f \to f^* \omega$ for some specific $\omega$ gives a bijection between the space $[X, K(G, n)]$ of maps $X \to K(G, n)$ modulo homotopy and $H^*(X, G)$. This leads to the idea of classifying spaces for vector bundles, and bundles over a given space can be classified via cohomology. This result also has deeper consequences; for example, it leads to a proof (although there are other ones available) that every closed, oriented $3$-manifold is the boundary of some compact, oriented $4$-manifold.
- For groups $G$ and $A$ with $A$ abelian, a central extension of $G$ by $A$ is a group $E$ for which $A\subset Z(E)$ and $E/A = G$. These groups are classified by the second group-homology group $H^2(G, A)$. The connection with group-cohomology and topological-cohomology is that, for reasons of abstract nonsense, $H^*(G)$ is precisely $H^*(K(G, 1))$, with $K(G, 1)$ the Eilenberg-MacLane space above. (We're now definitely dealing with, e.g., singular topology rather than de Rham cohomology, since we have no convenient smooth structure at hand, but the point is that an abstract question about group theory turns into a problem about topology.)
- In general, there are varieties of cohomology in commutative algebra, number thoery, physics, etc. At some point, it's like the concept of integral: the original impetus and most concrete application may be computing the area under a curve, but there are so many applications of it in so many different fields that it's hard to nail down one single thing that you can point and say it's designed for. Similarly, just as Riemann integrals are a first, concrete step toward a general idea of integration (leading to integrating differential forms, the Lebesgue integral, etc.), de Rham cohomology is one particular useful and concrete kind of cohomology theory.

2) Five is a lot of examples to give, and I'm not sure what exactly you're looking for here. There are a bunch of examples in Hatcher (in the topological rather than smooth case, but the principle and the axioms are effectively the same), and you can work through the known case of the genus $g$ oriented, closed surface.

Comment: Not OP, so maybe this is not appropriate, but I would still like to ask: De Rham's theorem states that de Rham cohomology coinides (naturally) with singular cohomology (with real coefficients) of the underlying smooth manifold. Is there any advantage to or problem that is easier to solve on the de Rhan side, than on passage to singular cohomology? Of course, being able to say something about diffferential forms is nice, but knowing exactness/closedness of certain forms, will this help with e.g. solving differential equations or something similarly analytic that singular cohomology won't see?

Comment: @ThePuix: Some examples that might be along the lines of what you're looking for: (1) Poincare duality has a nice interpretation in terms of the Hodge star operator, and ditto for the cup product and wedge prpoduct of forms; (2) Stokes' theorem requires some notion of differentiability; (3) Hodge theory, particularly representing cohomology classes with harmonic forms; (4) Chern-Weil theory; (5) Dolbeaut cohomology and similar extensions.

Comment: Thank! Your point (3) is something I’ve heard before: Do you have a canoncial example where this is useful, or a good reference I can look up?

Comment: @ThePuix: The particular thing I was referring to in (3) is the Hodge decomposition theorem, which states that on a closed, smooth manifold $X$, every element of $H^*(X)$ has a unique harmonic representative. It's a standard result; Lee's book, for example, should have it. As for applications, one particularly nice corollary is that it gives a one-line proof of Poincare duality: it's just the map $\alpha \to * \alpha$.

Answer (score 2):

Solutions of the equation of motion for a topological gauge field theory are given by closed form modulo exact form(the gauge symmetry). This is precisely the de Rham cohomology.

Please see  4.3 (page 20) and 4.4 (pages 20-21 ) of this reference:

https://uis.brage.unit.no/uis-xmlui/bitstream/handle/11250/2786275/no.uis%3Ainspera%3A79010903%3A35182444.pdf?sequence=1&isAllowed=y

This particular reference then goes further to show you the full story. It will enable you to give answers to physics problems without even lifting a finger to do a complicated calculation. POWER!

Extended commentary.

*You might want to read part B first*

**Part A**

There are three concepts here. Homology groups, Cohomology groups, and Equations of motion for say a Chern-Simons theory. A Chern-Simons theory is a name given to an object called an action which can be written as some combination of 3 forms at least according to Edward Witten’s formulation.

One of two central results from the Homology and Cohomology idea is that even though homology lives in the land of k-chains and linear transformations that take you from k to k-1 chains at least in Noether’s formulation, and Cohomology lives in the land of k-forms and derivatives that take you from k to k+ 1 forms, two theorems show that they measure the same holes. DeRham’s theorem says the kth homology and the kth cohomology are isomorphic. Similarly, Stokes-Cartan theorem holds.

The statement in the shared reference that “Solutions of the equation of motion are given by closed form modulo exact form (the gauge symmetry)”   for the three-dimensional Abelian Chern-Simons theory is just saying that if you write down the formula for the Cohomology group and just as he does in example 14, writing down the equations of motion from the action.

Many speculations (conjectures) could probably be drawn from this. I would leave such speculations to your imagination.

**PART B**

I think what you are probably really first thinking about are questions about the validity of basic notions of calculus, and how to identify and measure holes.

- Is the fundamental theorem of calculus always valid?
- What does Derham cohomology look like in different dimensions?
- What happens if I walk in circles on a cylinder?
- How can I see how mappings between k chains work?
- Etc
- . . .  Well, there is a short and precise video with this and most of the first applications of DeRham Cohomology.

This video:

https://youtu.be/2ptFnIj71SM?si=TrwTa4jZUxHfR0SP

Comment: I like the examples ;)

Comment: aww thank you :)

Comment: Unfortunately I don't understand much about the physics side of the Rham Cohomology. Although "equation of motion using the Rham Cohomology" I think sounds interesting I cannot really picture in my mind what that means. I would appreciate a more "layman terms" explanation. (Even via personal chat).

Comment: Hey, I tried a bit by adding some more words to my answer and also adding a link to an excellent video that does a great job of elucidating the concepts/applications using calculus and linear algebra ideas.  I think it should help a bit

Comment: I saw the video but if you could maybe explain a bit on the motion equations. In the classical sense I am used to some deterministic function $x(t)$ but using de Rham cohomology is a bit hard to understand the meaning